# Call nested function with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-5

Consider this code:

```js
(function a() {
    // Nested function
    function b() {
        console.log("Works!");
    }

    b();
})();
```

This code works, but would it be possible (in theory) to call `b()` if the name is inside a string (i.e. dynamic)?

If `b()` would be declared in the global scope, we could use `window[stringContainingName]();`. Is there a possibility in this case?

**This is only a theoretical question! I know that such code is bad design.**

Comment: What happens when you try? :P

Comment: @Jite What should I try?

Comment: there is one solution. But I cannot post it due downvote wave: `fname= 'b'; eval(fname+'();')`

Comment: How exactly using `eval('b()')` is better than `window['b']()`?

Comment: @chumkiu I'd give you a +1 in this case (this is only a theoretical question thus misusing *eval()* doesn't matter) ;) Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @raina77ow `window['b']` doesn't work unless you declare `b()` as a global function (as you did).

Comment: Ok, but in this case @Bergi suggestion - use a container object to limit the scope of a method that'll be called dynamically - is exactly what you need. And it's not better than `eval` just because it's not `eval`; the latter has its uses, of course. But not in this case, imo.

Comment: @raina77ow It's not about design here. I was just curious whether there is a way. In the end, there is only one solution: imitating the use of `b()` by calling `eval()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This code works, but would it be possible (in theory) to call b() if
>   the name is inside a string (i.e. dynamic)?

No, function declaration has the same rules for scope, so it's not possible even in theory (unless we talk about closures, of course).

> If b() would be declared in the global scope, we could use
>   windowstringContainingName; Is there a possibility in this case?

Yes, of course: this...

```
(function a() {
    // Nested function
    window.b = function() {
        console.log("Works!");
    }
    b();
})();
b(); // or window['b'](), or window.b()
```

... will log `'Works'` twice. I used explicit global object here, as in the strict mode direct assignment to `b` without declaring it (using `b = function() ...` instead of `window.b = function() ...`) will cause ReferenceError.

Comment: I do not fully understand the last sentence. How else can a function  (nested in another one) be declared to appear in the global scope?

Comment: With just `b = function()... ` instead of `window.b`. It's definitely not a good habit to have, but it does work in non-strict mode.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I forgot about not using *var* ;)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a possibility in this case?

Only by making the `b` function a property of an object:

```
(function a(name) {
    var fns = {
        b: function b() {
            console.log("Works!");
        }
    };

    // possibly secure by `if (fns.hasOwnProperty(name))`
    fns[name]();
})("b");
```

You will need to know the names of the functions in beforehand.

Comment: Both answeres were fine, but it was a little bit difficult to decide which one to accept because there was no 'real' solution to my question. Thanks for posting an answer :)